# Download and extract in a single line of shell

Tags: linux, shell, command

I should Get the source of GNU tar from Internet (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-latest.tar.gz)
and extract the list of all C header files included in all files of the source code in a single line of Shell, I know i should use pipelining and concretely the command wget but I don't know how to make it work.
If I do it by hand the list goes:

wordsplit.h
ws2tcpip.h
xalloc.h
xalloc-oversized.h
xattr-at.h
xattrs.h
xgetcwd.h
xsize.h

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange.  Worth updating the question with what commands you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works, but requires curl & tar to be present (usually available by default in most systems)

```
$ curl -sL -o- "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-latest.tar.gz" |tar -tz --wildcards --no-anchored '*.h'
tar-1.29/build-aux/snippet/_Noreturn.h
tar-1.29/build-aux/snippet/arg-nonnull.h
tar-1.29/build-aux/snippet/c++defs.h
tar-1.29/build-aux/snippet/unused-parameter.h
tar-1.29/build-aux/snippet/warn-on-use.h
tar-1.29/gnu/uniwidth/cjk.h
tar-1.29/gnu/argp.h
tar-1.29/gnu/argp-fmtstream.h
tar-1.29/gnu/argp-namefrob.h
tar-1.29/gnu/argp-version-etc.h
tar-1.29/gnu/bitrotate.h
tar-1.29/gnu/c-ctype.h
tar-1.29/gnu/c-strcase.h
tar-1.29/gnu/full-write.h
tar-1.29/gnu/gettext.h
tar-1.29/gnu/localcharset.h
tar-1.29/gnu/mbuiter.h
tar-1.29/gnu/progname.h
tar-1.29/gnu/se-context.in.h
tar-1.29/gnu/se-selinux.in.h
---------many more files follow-------------
```

Or even combined with grep:

```
$ curl -sL -o- "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-latest.tar.gz" |tar -zt |grep '/src/.*\.h$'
tar-1.29/src/arith.h
tar-1.29/src/common.h
tar-1.29/src/tar.h
tar-1.29/src/xattrs.h
```

Considering that your question talks about *"extract the list of all C header files"* i assume you need just a listing like above.

In case you want to get the contents of those `.h` files, you can use something like this to "dump" the contents on your screen:

```
$ curl -sL -o- "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-latest.tar.gz" |tar -xzO --wildcards --no-anchored '*.h'
```

Tip: Combine with `|less` at the end for easy reading.

Finally , to make it complete , as advised by @don_crissti to extract the '*.h' files in your local drive instead of screen dumping, you can use:

```
$ curl -sL -o- "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-latest.tar.gz" |tar -xzf - --wildcards --no-anchored '*.h'
```

A new folder `tar-1.29` will be created under your current working directory including all `.h` files.

```
$ ls -ld tar-1.29
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 24 01:48 tar-1.29
$ ls -l tar-1.29
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 24 01:48 build-aux
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 24 01:48 gnu
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 24 01:48 lib
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 24 01:48 src
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 24 01:48 tests
```

Comment: @don_crissti: I agree that the question is unclear. Since it says *extract the list*, it's quite possible that the OP wants `tar -t` and not `tar -x`.

Comment: @G-Man Exactly this is what i also thought....